# How to detect Xamarin Forms tabbed page click - iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

My scenario is, I have a `Tabbed` page in `Xamarin Forms`:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var playPage = new NavigationPage(new PlayPage())
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "play.png"
        };
        var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
        { 
            Title = "Settings",
            Icon = "settings.png"
        };
        var favoritesPage = new NavigationPage(new FavoritesPage())
        {
            Title = "Favorites",
            Icon = "fave.png"
        };
        var aboutPage = new NavigationPage(new AboutPage())
        {
            Title = "About",
            Icon = "info.png"
        };

        Children.Add(playPage);
        Children.Add(favoritesPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(aboutPage);
    }
}
```

I want to add a pause and play function to my app. On start up, the `PlayPage` would initially have the `play.png` icon and when I click on the `PlayPage` again it would change the icon to `pause.png`. Page is not changing just the page icon. Anyone has any idea how this could be done?

**Edit:**

So I have created a custom renderer, in `OnElementChanged` I utilize the `ViewControllerSelected`:

```
var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;
if (null != tabbarController)
{
    tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabBarReselected;
}
```

And my `OnTabBarReselected` I have:

```
private void OnTabBarReselected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e)
{
    switch (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title)
    {
       case "Play":
          TabBar.SelectedItem.Title = "Pause";
          TabBar.SelectedItem.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pause.png");
          break;
    }
}
```

This only does half of the work. It changes the `Title` of the selected tab bar from `Play` to `Pause` after I click on the same tab but not the `Icon`. The icon remains "play.png" until I get out of that tab page (selecting another tab). Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a custom renderer to pull this off. There are some implementations on James Montemagno's blog where he talks about changing the icons.

- iOS:
  http://motzcod.es/post/138225183932/tintcolor-selectedimage-xamarin-forms-ios
- Droid:
  http://motzcod.es/post/157544468267/xamarin-forms-android-selected-and-unselected-tab-colors

This is however not necessarily related to your requirement of tapping the icon and changing that specific icon since all this code only runs when the page initially loads. It could be a nice starting point though. Check in there if there's a property on TabbedPage that changes when you tap on the current tab and change the icon at that point.

You also have a `OnCurrentPageChanged` event you can override in `TabbedPage`, but that isn't called when the page is already active.